# How to deep copy duplicate a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, deep-copy

I have a list of dicts:

```
my_list = [
  {
    'key1': 'value1',
  },
  {
    'key2': 'value2',
  },
]
```

I want to multiply the list like so:

```
my_new_list = [
  {
    'key1': 'value1',
  },
  {
    'key2': 'value2',
  },
  {
    'key1': 'value1',
  },
  {
    'key2': 'value2',
  },
]
```

I tried the `my_list * 2` approach, but it creates shallow copies meaning if I modify one dict it ends up modifying many others in the list. I guess I am looking for a deep copy.

I also tried this:

`my_new_list = [my_list[i % len(my_list)] for i in range(4)]`

But same issue.

This approach worked but it doesn't feel very pythonic to me which is why I am looking for a better answer.

```
from copy import deepcopy

my_new_list = [deepcopy(my_list[i % len(my_list)]) for i in range(4)]
```

How do I create this deep copy multiplied list?

Comment: how about my_new_list = deepcopy(my_list) + deepcopy(my_list) That uses deepcopy, and gives the order you requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the multiplication approach with `dict.copy()` assuming that your dicts are shallow like the ones in your example.

```
l = [{'k1': 'v1'}, {'k2': 'v2'}]

result = [d.copy() for d in l * 2]
result[0]['k1'] = 'changed'
print(result)
# [{'k1': 'changed'}, {'k2': 'v2'}, {'k1': 'v1'}, {'k2': 'v2'}]
```

Comment: You'll still want to deepcopy, because we don't know what's really in those dicts, but otherwise this works, and might be better because it builds the new list with a list comprehension.

Comment: @KennyOstrom - good comment. Added note to that effect to the answer to avoid reader confusion.

Answer (score 1):

you can use copy module to deep copy,
try this out

```
import copy
my_list = [{'key1': 'value1',},{'key2': 'value2',},]
my_list = my_list + copy.deepcopy(my_list)
my_list[0]['key1'] = 'next'
print(my_list)
```

Comment: well, you don't *have* to.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `dict.copy()` method to make a literal copy of the `dict` object.

```
my_new_list = [my_list[i % len(my_list)].copy() for i in range(len(my_list) * 2)]
```

Now to verify let's change the value of the first dict object,

```
my_new_list[0]['key1'] = 'value3'
```

```
print(my_new_list)
```

Output:

```
[{'key1': 'value3'}, {'key2': 'value2'}, {'key1': 'value1'}, {'key2': 'value2'}]
```

Comment: This could be dangerous. We don't know that all the dicts are safe for shallow copy, just the ones presented in OP. I am pretty sure the "pythonic" concerns were talking about using modulo arithmetic tricks (which I am personally fine with, as are most), not about whether using a library that ships with python is "pythonic"

Answer (score 0):

How about this? Seems very *pythonic* to me...

```py
my_list.extend(deepcopy(my_list))
```

This will, of course, override `my_list`. If you want to keep it, just deepcopy `my_list` to `my_new_list` beforehand (or perform an addition of two deepcopies of `my_list`).

This way is supposed to work with any object (that can be deepcopied) rather than relying on `dict`'s defined behavior

Answer (score 0):

I'm struggling with why the original poster's solution is deemed "not pythonic." You really need a reason to throw that label around. But looking at their modulo arithmetic answer, I'm guessing this is not simply doubling the list, but using it as a repeating template to fill a new list to an arbitrary size.

```
from copy import deepcopy
from itertools import islice, cycle
def fill(iterable, size):
    return map(deepcopy, islice(cycle(iterable), size))

print (list(fill(my_list, 4)))
```

itertools.cycle gives you the repeating behavior
itertools.islice lets you specify the number of elements
deepcopy is for reusability, in case the individual dicts have internal data that might not be safe in a shallow copy (unlike the posted example) -- and because it was in the question title.
map lets me return an iterable of the deepcopy results, so if you want a list you can have it, but you can use it however you like.

For the record, I was happy with the modulo arithmetic solution. Math still works in python!